# Creating New Columns out of strings in cell

Tags: r, string, substr

I have a data frame that looks like

```
                                     inx   time
1    201566.202331.203500.203924.1628390 915.22
2    201571.202696.203095.203932.1628371 864.86
3     202329.203081.203090.203468.203994 743.54
4    201572.202339.203114.203507.1627763 597.34
5     101107.201587.202689.203087.203469 592.97
6    201152.201954.202711.203506.1626167 555.01
7    200768.201586.201980.202695.1627783 542.16
8    201143.202681.202694.203935.1628369 504.30
9  202357.202697.1626161.1627741.1628368 499.81
10   201937.202324.203497.204060.1628378 499.60
```

And Instead of the 5 sets of numbers separated by a period, I want 5 columns + plus the column at the end for time

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` with `sep="."` to read that as five columns

```
cbind(read.table(text = df1$inx, header = FALSE, sep="."), df1['time'])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(inx = c("201566.202331.203500.203924.1628390", 
"201571.202696.203095.203932.1628371", "202329.203081.203090.203468.203994", 
"201572.202339.203114.203507.1627763", "101107.201587.202689.203087.203469", 
"201152.201954.202711.203506.1626167", "200768.201586.201980.202695.1627783", 
"201143.202681.202694.203935.1628369", "202357.202697.1626161.1627741.1628368", 
"201937.202324.203497.204060.1628378"), time = c(915.22, 864.86, 
743.54, 597.34, 592.97, 555.01, 542.16, 504.3, 499.81, 499.6)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option with `tstrsplit`

```
> setDT(df)[, c(Map(as.numeric, tstrsplit(inx, "\\.")), time = .(time))]
        V1     V2      V3      V4      V5   time
 1: 201566 202331  203500  203924 1628390 915.22
 2: 201571 202696  203095  203932 1628371 864.86
 3: 202329 203081  203090  203468  203994 743.54
 4: 201572 202339  203114  203507 1627763 597.34
 5: 101107 201587  202689  203087  203469 592.97
 6: 201152 201954  202711  203506 1626167 555.01
 7: 200768 201586  201980  202695 1627783 542.16
 8: 201143 202681  202694  203935 1628369 504.30
 9: 202357 202697 1626161 1627741 1628368 499.81
10: 201937 202324  203497  204060 1628378 499.60
```